# How to properly call Shapley axioms (especially symmetry/anonymity)?

Tags: terminology, game-theory

The game-theoretical terminology is quite confusing. At the original Shapley paper, the **symmetry** axiom means that the Shapley value is invariant with respect to any players' permutation, i.e. $$ \Phi _{\pi  i}( \pi \cdot v)=\Phi _i(v) $$
But at the many modern texts, including textbooks, the ***symmetry*** means different axiom, something like "mirroring"

If $v (S\cup \{i\})=v (S\cup \{j\})$ for any coalition $S: i,j\notin S$, then $\Phi _i(v)=\Phi _j(v)$

and the original *symmetry* axiom is now called **anonymity**.

Which of them terminologies is clearer in today's game theory? How to avoid confusion? I take care of this article on Wikipedia.